# Excel 2013 Pivot table, how to filter rows/columns before pivoting

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, pivot-table

I have some raw data in my spreadsheet with columns like `role, role status, object, object status`, so the data indicates the relationship between role and object.

The some data view looks like

```
role1,1,obj1,1
role1,1,obj2,0
role2,0,obj1,1
role3,1,obj3,1
```

I want to see a matrix to represent what role can access what object. Meanwhile I only want to include `role status = 1` and `object status = 1` in my pivot table.

```
╔══════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║      ║ role1 ║ role3 ║
╠══════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║ obj1 ║     1 ║       ║
║ obj3 ║       ║     1 ║
╚══════╩═══════╩═══════╝
```

I can generate pivot table from data easily, but I have no clue how to do a pre-filtering of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do exactly what you're looking for.

Closest workaround is to add a new column to your data where you enter different values for rows to include / exclude. Then it's easy to filter on pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

All data sets should be columns and then apply pivot table to make the summery table as you like.  Example:

```
COURSE  SEMISTER
C11    First
C12    Second
C13    First
C14    Second
```

One pivot table will be:

```
Row Labels  Count of COURSE
First          2
Second         2
Grand Total    4
```